# Input command in another terminal via python

Tags: python

I am writing a python for our daily build.
My python will run a script to execute build code command as below.

```py
subprocess.call("./xxx.sh", shell=True)
```

There will pop up another terminal when running the script and I need to enter "make dtbs" command by myself.
I tried to use `subprocess.call("make dtbs", shell=True)`, but it seems not work in another terminal.
Does there anyone know how to do that?

Thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way:

```
import os
os.system("your command here")
```

exp:

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```

Another way, you can use subprocess's call:

```
from subprocess import call
call('echo "be easier said than done"', shell=True)
```

or:

```
call(['echo', 'be easier said than done'])
```

If you want to capture the output:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['echo', 'be easier said than done']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

o, e = proc.communicate()

print('Output: ' + o.decode('ascii'))
print('Error: '  + e.decode('ascii'))
print('code: ' + str(proc.returncode))
```

Comment: Hi Parham sagharichi ha, I follow your step, but my command still cannot send automatically to the new terminal pop out.

Comment: please try this command,




subprocess.call_in_new_window('echo "be easier said than done"', shell=True)

Comment: I found another way to modify my script and no new terminal pop out anymore. Thanks for your support.